# Commenting debugging suggestions to an off-topic question

Tags: discussion, comments

Hmm.. is it OK to comment a suggestion for debugging to a question that is off-topic for no code etc, maybe even while voting to close it?  I'm specifically referrring to this question and my comment: [Receive interrupt not triggered in controller after serialport.write() command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51201701/758133).  Was my comment useful overall, don't care or not useful overall?

There's no doubt that it's a bad question and deserves a close-vote but, if the OP makes sure that it's really a software issue, and posts some code, it could be made on-topic.  If that does not happen, it's still good advice to a user whose Q. is probably going to be closed, as it is.

I'm not sure is such a comment is classed as a 'request for clarification' or not?

Comment: I'm not sure why that comment would be problematic. You're suggesting things the OP might do in order to narrow down their problem by the looks of it.

Comment: I have encountered this user several times before, he has always found *something* to criticize in a post or comment.  A constructive way to deal with it is to consider he's operating with very high standards, impossible to reach for mere mortals.  No response or follow-up necessary.  Nothing wrong with your comment, this is the kind of assistance needed for the OP to turn his question into something with lasting value.

Comment: IMO: always, if you don't mind offering up your time and energy. If it helps get someone on track, without "harming" the site (the Q will either be deleted or "fixed"), why not? I often post pointers to end-user Q's in a comment, while also telling the person they need to go elsewhere. That little bit of info often gives them the search terms they're lacking for finding the answer for themselves. And it leaves a better impression of the site, even when "rejecting" them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's not really a request for clarification — maybe we should add "guidance for narrowing down the problem and improving the question" to the mix ;)

But in all seriousness, I agree with ivarni. Anything that leads to an improvement of the question (especially if it takes the question from off-topic to on-topic!), anything that leads to the user being better at what they do is fine to suggest in a comment, provided that it's relevant to the question at hand. As long as you don't be sarcastic or intentionally condescending about it (not saying you are... but *I've* been there myself). Of course, I'm sure you're aware that some users will react badly to any form of constructive advice no matter how nicely you try to put it — that's not your fault, and as long as your conscience is clear and you don't respond in kind to their bad attitude that's all that matters.

The comments you've left on that question are on the right track, IMO.

Comment: I'd argue it is a request for clarification, like "What version of Python are you on? You can find out with `python --version`." You're asking them for additional details, and specifying how to get them.

Comment: @Nic Hartley: Indeed, I see where you're coming from. It all comes down to how you phrase it.